# Auto reload of modified file looses pan position in Zathura

Tags: pdf, zathura

I use [Zathura](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) as my PDF reader. It is great but I have an issue with the auto-reload. When I compile a `.tex` file, its associated `.pdf` file is automatically reloaded in Zathura and correctly displays the modifications I made. My problem is that if I had zoomed into a particular region of my `.pdf` page —let's say the lower right corner— the reloaded `.pdf` is now focused on the upper right part of the page.

It is very annoying because every time I compile my `.tex`  files I have to reposition again in the `.pdf` file.  **Is there a way to configure Zathura so that it remembers what it should display?** (Note that the zoom is not affected by the auto-reload, only the position is.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had the desired behavior and then suddenly it behaved the same as you described.
I solved this problem by reinstalling `zathura` and `zathura-pdf-mupdf`.

Hope this helps someone.

Edit: additional system information,
the versions have not changed in the process.

```bsh
$ zathura -v
zathura 0.4.7
girara 0.3.5 (runtime: 0.3.5)
(plugin) pdf-mupdf (0.3.6) (/usr/lib/zathura/libpdf-mupdf.so)

$ uname -a # this is a variant of arch linux
Linux artix 5.9.6-artix1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri, 06 Nov 2020 12:04:06 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Would you mind adding which version of `zathura` you have installed now, and if that version has somehow changed during the reinstall? Also, on which OS version and flavor did this help?

Comment: @AdminBee: a lot of things have changed since 2015... but I currently use debian 10 with packages:´zathura 0.4.3-1´ and ´zathura-pdf-poppler 0.2.9-1´

Comment: @PinkFloyd Yes, I would assume so. This is why I asked for the clarification, as a new version may of course solve shortcomings of a previous version. So the question is: do you still have the original problem, and could therefore this answer solve your problem if indeed it is still there?

Comment: @AdminBee No idea, sorry!

Comment: @AdminBee well, of course I can't tell whether or not this may help solving the original problem. I had a similar problem, reinstalled the same version and it worked. Before reinstall I googled and stumbled across this post and thought maybe help someone who is having the same issue.

Comment: We all understand that there is no guarantee, but the additional information I requested may help someone who similarly stumbled upon this post to assess whether this solution might work for them, too. Also, it might help others investigate the root of the problem.